# How to solve Submitted a post into database in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

When submit a question into database, then show error anyone help me where problem?

Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException

question

E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php

```
// assignment to the model, and all others will just be ignored.
if ($this->isFillable($key))
{
$this->setAttribute($key, $value);
}
elseif ($totallyGuarded)
{
throw new MassAssignmentException($key);
}
}
```

Comment: What error is thrown? Where in the code is it thrown? and by Question do you mean Query?

Answer (score 3):

You are not showing any error there, well what i can guess from there is , you are getting error on your model. May be you haven't set fillable correctly. You can set your model in this way

```
class User extends Eloquent{

 protected $table = 'users';    

 protected $fillable = array('firstname','lastname','address');

 }
```